# Commit Git subtree metadata?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a Git managed project "Project"
2. I add a Git repo, "Library," as a subtree to "Project" and push it online.
3. My coworker clones "Project"

Problem is my coworker's cloned repo has no reference to Library's remote or that Project contains a subtree. The classes from Library appear to have always been a part of Project's repo. How does my coworker know they may be able to pull changes from Library's remote?

Is it possible to store subtree metadata in the Git repo so that when the project is cloned it is aware of subtrees and their remotes, or do they need to be configured every time a project is cloned?

Comment: I believe the behavior you would like to have is called a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Adding these to a repository allows those who clone the main repo to automatically get the subtree, which is a separate git history. Is that what you need? I can give a longer write up as an answer if so.